# How to rewrite ActiveSheet to SPECIFIC sheet and column?

Tags: google-apps-script

In this [example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15Yw4k_tCW7yhGHMzpjiRGZtypL2lyAhbb0PJAnAMij0/edit?usp=sharing) I am using this to shuffle a selected range:

```
 function shuffleRows() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Ark5");
  var range = sheet.getRange("I2:I8");
/*  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var rg=sh.getDataRange();
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  var lr=sh.getLastRow();*/
  sheet.sort(function(a,b){return Math.floor(Math.random()*range)-Math.floor(Math.random()*range);
  });
  rg.setValues(sheet);
}

function onOpen() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var entries = [{
    name : "Bland alle dyrene",
    functionName : "shuffleRows",
  }];
  sheet.addMenu("Bland alle dyrene", entries);
};
```

Is is possible to specify both sheet and selcted range i.e.

```
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(MY SPECIFIC SHEET);
  var range = sheet.getActiveRange(MY SPECIFIC ROW);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you just want to:

- Return a sheet that has a specific name.
- Return the range corresponding to a specified A1 notation.

If that's the case, you just need to use [Spreadsheet.getSheetByName](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getSheetByName(String)) and [Sheet.getRange](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(String)):

```js
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Ark2");
var range = sheet.getRange("B2:B");
```

#### Reference:

- [Spreadsheet.getSheetByName(name)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getSheetByName(String))
- [Sheet.getRange(a1Notation)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(String))

Comment: @lamblichus Excuse me for reentering this question but as I evolved my project from numbers to names I also failes to edit the total formula. Will You please take another look at my new formula inserted in the original question?

Comment: @AllanBech I'm sorry, I don't understand your issue. Also, since this was not in the original question, I'd suggest you to create another question, and explain what is your current issue.

Comment: Thank You. I will open a new question.